# Car insurance - Probability

Tags: probability

A car insurance policy insures as many men as women.

The probability that a woman will claim the insurance in any given year is independent of the other years and is equal to $\beta$.

The same holds to the male persons with the probability $\alpha$.

Now let's assume that the insurance company pulls a person at random.

(a) What is the probability that this random person will claim insurance this year?

(b) What is the probability that the person will claim the insurance in two consecutive years?

$$$$

For question (a) : The probability to take a woman is equal to the probability to take a man, which is $\frac{1}{2}$.

So is the probability that this random person will claim insurance this year equal to $p=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \beta+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \alpha$ ?

For question (b) : Since each year is independent is the probability equal to $p^2$, where $p$ is the probability from (a) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for a) is OK. So it is

$p = p_1 = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \beta+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \alpha$

The solution for b) is not this. It is

$p_2=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \beta^2+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \alpha^2$

because the problem says: first they pull a person at random
(either a man or woman - probability $1/2$),
and then this (particular) person makes claims in two consecutive years
(probability $\alpha^2$ or $\beta^2$ depending on if they picked
a man or woman).

I think what you have calculated as $p^2$ is the probability that:

1. a randomly chosen person A claims this year, say in 2021
   **AND**
2. a randomly chosen person B (it may happen that $A=B$ or $A \ne B$) claims in the year 2022

But this is not the event whose probability they want in b).

Comment: I see!! Thank you!!:-)